# Tutte–Grothendieck invariants and Tutte polynomial. Is this property even used in the proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, simplicial-complex, matroids

I am using “Matroids: A Geometric Introduction” by Gordon and McNulty.

On page 337, in Theorem 9.19 Tutte-Grothendieck invariants are defined. The theorem itself gives their description in terms of Tutte polynomial. I cannot understand how the first point of the definition (invariance) is used in the proof. I get the feeling that it is not used at all. Is it true? If so, then the first point of the definition still holds, but now this is an elementary consequence of this theorem and invariance of Tutte polynomial.

This definition is combined with the statement of the theorem, so the authors could add the first point to the definition in order to emphasize that Tutte-Grothendieck invariant is indeed an invariant, but it turned out to be messy, because it makes the impression that without this condition the theorem is false.

Thank you.

[image: Definition and theorem statement]
[image: Proof]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the point is that conditions (3) and (4) don't even really make sense without (1): what do $f(I)$ and $f(L)$ mean?  There are lots of different choices of an isthmus $I$ or a loop $L$ (which are isomorphic but not equal), and so we can't talk about a well-defined value of $f$ on them unless we know that $f$ always takes the same value on these isomorphic matroids.  Similarly, in the statement of the conclusion $$f(M)=t(M;f(I),f(L)),$$ you need to know what $f(I)$ and $f(L)$ mean.  If you just pick some specific $I$ and $L$ in order to interpret $f(I)$ and $f(L)$ in this conclusion, then the base case of the induction uses assumption (1): you need to know that if $M$ is an isthmus then $f(M)=f(I)$, and if $M$ is a loop then $f(M)=f(L)$.

(Separately, let me remark that there appear to be a large number of minor errors in the statement of Theorem 9.19.  For instance, in conditions (3) and (4), presumably it should be assumed that $e$ is an isthmus or a loop, respectively.  The domain of $f$ should consist of matroids, not isomorphism classes of matroids (if the domain is isomorphism classes, then (1) is automatic!).  There should also be an assumption about the value $f$ takes on the empty matroid, which should really be the base case of the proof instead of the case $|E|=1$.)

Comment: Let's look at $(3)$, for example. We know that $M$ has an isthmus $e$. Why can't we say that $f(M)=f(I)f(M/e)$, where by $I$ we denote submatroid of our specific $M$ on $\{e\}$? If this is a legit approach, then I do agree about minor errors except for the last one. For isthmus $I$ we have from $(3)$ that $f(I)=f(I)f(\{\emptyset\})$, so $f(I)=0$ or $f(\{\emptyset\})=1$ and it is enough for the base case (samely for a loop).

Comment: Well sure, you could say that.  But this still doesn't solve the problem that the very statement $f(M)=t(M;f(I),f(L))$ requires a fixed choice of $I$ and $L$, which may not be the same as the submatroids of $M$ you use in (3) and (4).  If you run through how the inductive proof computes $f(M)$ for any fixed $M$, you end up using the values of $f(I)$ and $f(L)$ for a bunch of different isthmuses and loops, and you need to know those values are all the same.

Comment: You really do need an assumption about the empty matroid; without it, then if $f(I)$ and $f(L)$ are both $0$, $f$ could take any value at all on the empty matroid, whereas the Tutte polynomial takes the value $1$.

Comment: Ok, you're right. It inspires last question: imagine that we replace $(1)$ by "$f(M_1)=f(M_2)$ if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are isomorphic matroids on ground set of cardinality $1$". It seems like it must make the definition sensible (even without mentioning submatroids) and the proof  correct. Am I right?

Comment: Sure, that would work.